# A custom function to return the length of a string

Tags: python, string, function

I want to define a function which takes an input from the user, returns the length of the input string and prints this out.

I have the following code:

```
def str_length(my_string):
    my_string = input("give me a string: ")
    return len(my_string)
print(str_length(my_string))
```

This code does not work. When I exchange the parameter in the last line to "hello" the code works.

```
def str_length(my_string):
    my_string = input("give me a string: ")
    return len(my_string)
print(str_length("hello"))
```

Can anyone explain to me why the first code does not work while the second one works? I am totally confused :-(

Comment: Why is the function taking a parameter at all? It's not using it

Comment: Thank you! I am new to coding. I thought, I need to add a parameter. But now I understand :-)

Comment: "``This code does not work.``" is not a helpful statement. Please provide the input, the actual output and the expected output in your question. If your code is throwing an error, you should provide the complete error stack in your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You may find the explanations given at http://idownvotedbecau.se/ helpful to avoid accidentally posting stuff which has downvote reasons within.

Comment: @Mike Scotty: thank for the clarification! I will make sure to be more precise in the future :-)

Comment: @Alfe: thanks! I assume you are referring to the same issue as Mike Scotty. As mentioned, I am new to StackOverflow and I will be more precise in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define it like this:

```
def str_length():
    my_string = input("give me a string: ")
    return len(my_string)
print(str_length())
```

When you call the function with `my_string` you get `NameError` because there is no `my_string` define yet. you define it inside the function. (After you call it). that is the reason.

Thanks to @prashantrana, You can also define your function like this:

```
def str_length(my_string):
    return len(my_string)

my_string = input("give me a string: ")
print(str_length(my_string))
```

The difference here is that we get input from user out of the function scope, the pass it to function.

Comment: your welcome @Comtron, Please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar  you can add another way where user pass the string as parameter to the function . both case

Comment: @Comtron also you can check the gray button beside and turn to green. :)

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar: I am a bit lost (sorry! new to the stackoverflow). which grey button do you mean?

Comment: no problem, it looks like a check mark, gray checkmark. it is on the left side of upvote and downvote buttons.

Comment: merci kheili mamnoon :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @UnholySheep pointed out, your function is taking a parameter it doesn't seem to need.

Let's break it down

```
Def str_length (): # start of function definition
    # promt user for the string and put it in the variable "my _string"
    my_string = input ("give me a string:")
    # return the length of input string 
    return len(my_string)

print(str_length ()) # the function is called inside print () and therefore returns the length of the user input string to print () to be printed on screen.
```